# CGSize to pixels / points confusion

Tags: ios, cgsize

I have got this code:

```
CGRect _frame = container.frame;
CGFloat height = _frame.size.height
```

This code gives me the height of the view but in what units? Is there a way to convert it to pixels or points so I could visualize it a bit better?

I have read in the documentation that CGSize is a vector rather than a physical value but that doesn't me help much in understanding it.

Thank you!

[CGSize documentation](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/coregraphics/cgsize?language=objc)

Comment: It's in points. For instance, if you do `CGRect rect = [UIScreen mainscreen].frame`, you won't have the "resolution in pixel as sold by Marketing" in a device. You have the `scale` (of `UIScreen`) factor if needed. But usually, we use points for most of our work, because it's not relevant in a pixel size (Retina, Retina3, etc.), we just need to position our view at some location in points.

Comment: Of course it is. Thank you mate!

Comment: Look at the documentation for `UIView frame` (or `bounds`). It states: *"The coordinates of the frame rectangle are always specified in points."*.